# Datatables - adding filter function to existing script

Tags: jquery, database, datatables, filtering

I have installed Datatables and have the activation script for the example but I am looking to add column filter to my datatable but can't seem to get it activate the table and add filtering and gives an error.

Any way to adjust the below code to add filtering to each column and for it to work?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "ssp.php", 
    } );
} );    
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').DataTable( {
            initComplete: function () {
                this.api().columns().every( function () {
                    var column = this;
                    var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                        .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
                        .on( 'change', function () {
                            var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                                $(this).val()
                            );

                            column
                                .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                                .draw();
                        } );

                    column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                        select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
                    } );
                } );
            }
        } );
    } );
```

Answer (score 0):

You initialize your table twice with `$('#example').DataTable({})` but it only should be done once hence the error.

Also with server-side processing `"serverSide": true` not all column values will be immediately available, only current page. Therefore you need to do either

- Switch to client-side processing mode. After combining two `$('#example').DataTable({})` calls into one, your code would be just fine.
- Retrieve all possible values from the server via Ajax and populate the drop-down boxes. This would require more front-end and back-end code, and you would need to discard your code in `initComplete` handler.